# Is there any difference between two terminologies viz. descriptive statistics and descriptive analytics

Tags: statistics, data-science, analytics

I am trying to understand if there is any difference between two terminologies viz. descriptive statistics and descriptive analytics. Googling didn't give clear picture on what is common and what is different between these two terminologies.

It appears that both terminologies summarizes and analyses the data with the help of statistics.
So does it means that they are just same? Statistician may like to mention descriptive statistics while data scientist may call it descriptive analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same.
Descriptive statistics summarizes or describes characteristics of a data set.
Descriptive statistics consists of two basic categories of measures:
measures of central tendency
measures of variability or spread.

Measures of central tendency describe the center of a data set.Like  mean, median, or mode, which measures the most common patterns of the analyzed data set.

Measures of variability or spread describe the dispersion of data within the data set.describing the shape and spread of the data set. Range, quartiles, absolute deviation, and variance